# How to do some custom bash scripting command?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to use some commands on my Orange pi zero within reach, for example: I want to execute one command on ubuntu, and I want to have every commands on 1 file.

***my_file*** (without ending in .sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
alias myip='curl ipinfo.io/ip'
alias tururu='echo it works'
```

Have this file, and chmod -x was executed on this file, but when I do on terminal "sh my_file myip", doesn't do anything, but didn't give me an error, so what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you mean to: `source my_file && myip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh myfile myip` is one command; it doesn't run `sh myfile`, *then* `myip`. Your script should just look like

```
#!/bin/sh
curl ipinfo.io/ip
echo it works
```

then run as `sh myfile` (or `myfile`, assuming it is executable and located in a directory on your path).

If, instead, you want to execute `myfile` so that you can subsequently use `myip` and `tururu` as commands, you need to *source* the file:

```
$ source myfile
$ myip
192.0.2.24
$ tururu
it works
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks you so much! You save me from the suicide! Jeje